# Visualizing 10 random test examples, the predicted labels, and the actual label from MNIST data set

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to visualize 10 randome test examples, the predicted lables and the actual labels for MNIST data set. but I am getting this error

> TypeError: Invalid shape (28, 28, 1) for image data

[image: error screenshot]

Can anyone please help me fixing the error? Is it the right approach to visualize test examples, the predicated labels and the actual labels?

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
print(tf.__version__)
    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
    (training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
    training_images = training_images.reshape(60000, 28, 28, 1)
    training_images = training_images / 255.0

    #visualizing 10 random test examples 
    for i in range(10): 
      pyplot.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
      pyplot.imshow(test_images[i], cmap=pyplot.get_cmap('gray'))
      pyplot.show()
    
    
    test_images = test_images.reshape(10000, 28, 28, 1)
    test_images = test_images/255.0
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(training_images, training_labels, epochs=10)
    test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
    print(test_acc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to remove the last axis such that your images are of size (28, 28) instead of (28,28,1). Pyplot expects either RGB images with 3 dimensions or black and white images with only 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pyplot.imshow(np.squeeze(test_images[i]), cmap=pyplot.get_cmap('gray'))
```